# How to make application trusted to outlook

Tags: .net, outlook-2007

I have created one application which is reading outlook mail, but when user install that application in their system and run it; they are getting pop up from outlook saying that "Some external application want to access your outlook, do you want to grant access to it?.... ". How can I make my application trusted to outlook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would be to create the application as an add-in in Outlook.
Add-ins are trusted.

Another way would be to use a 3th party component like "outlook redemption"

Comment: I have already written application, I am not sure how can I make this application as an outlook add in. Could you help me guiding the possible ways?

Comment: You could look into VSTO to create an addin. You might have to change some things tough as an outlook addin is executed from within outlook (You'd add buttons to the toolbar/ribbon of outlook so the user can access them)