# Trsuted Outlook session for non-add-in assembly?

Tags: .net, outlook

We have a .NET Framework desktop application accessing Outlook via PIAs (we read, create, and send e-mails using multiple accounts in Outlook). Is there a way to avoid the security guard warnings, i.e. by signing the accessing assembly and configuring this certificate as trustworthy for Outlook? A VSTO add-in would be granted a trusted Session object, but we want to avoid creating a VSTO add-in as well as using Redemption.
Drawbacks:

- Redemption (we have already used it) must be separately deployed/installed.
- VSTO add-in must also be deployed separately, and the communication between the add-in and our desktop application is an additional overhead.

Note: The following similar question/answer is a few years old, so there might be news about this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5990247/9098649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to use Redemption, installing an up-to-date antivirus app (if you can control the environment) is the only way.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer (and thank you for Redemption; we want to avoid it in this scenario, but it has served us well in others)! How does the security guard decide whether the antivirus app is up-to-date? The Microsoft documentation is vague about this.

Comment: I don't know the details of the API, but Windows can check if the virus definitions etc. are recent.

Comment: Thank you! The following page confirms that: [Security Behavior of the Outlook Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/security-behavior-of-the-outlook-object-model)